# Are plumbers required to provide specs for the job they have done if asked by the homeowner?

Tags: plumbing

A plumber installed a bleeder port in our upstairs bathroom and a valve to feed the frost=free facet downstairs in the garage. He never told us how the system works? The bleeder was left open and our downstairs is flooded out. The plumber created the problem because a bleeder-port isn't needed when you have a frost-free facet.

We wonder if the plumber is required to make up a plan, or specifications, and outline the project, so that inspectors and the homeowner can see if he did was what proposed? We had a contractor come in to do our heating, it's a disaster, and we got the specs and learned he didn't do anything at all as required.

Comment: Did the plumber not explain their plans before starting the work? Were you not afforded the chance to ask questions about the system? If you know that the bleeder-port isn't needed when you have a frost-free facet then why was the plumber allowed to do such a thing? Did you set up some sort of bait for this plumber to do work in hopes of suing them? If they were rude the whole time and not approachable then you might be able to sue them for damages arising from not making you aware of the screwy system they installed.

Comment: Monkey Zeus, thanks for your response. W

Comment: Monkey Zeus, thanks for your response.  A builder erected our new home. I only learned, on this website, in the last few days, that the valve is called a bleeder port and how to use the system. The plumber never explained anything to us.  We have a home warranty company involved, and we are asking for the plumbing design to be changed to downstairs and to be done in copper, like the rest of the house, not in plastic like in the bathroom. The specs might show that what we want could have been in the original plans? And, no sir, we are not trying to bait anyone.

Comment: Did the plumber work for you or for the home builder?    Did you open the supply valve in the bathroom?  If yes, how did you not notice water spraying under pressure out the bleed valve?  I would expect it to spray violently, perhaps splashing into your face, in a way that is hard not to notice.  Or if you did not open it, are you saying it was gushing water from the time it was installed? Was the home delivered to you already flooded?  For how long was it flooded?

Comment: What was the purpose of the bleeder valve? Frost-free faucets do not need a bleeder valve. The fact that there was one is odd, but not the root cause of the problem. If the bleeder valve was closed, no flood. How did it get open / who left it open?

Comment: To jay613. The plumber worked for the builder. The builder instructed us to open the supply valve to use the garden hose. No mention was made of a bleeder port. We were watering our new lawn, I opened the supply valve and took off to water the lawn. 22 hours later I heard a dripping sound and the bottom floor was flooded I ran to the vanity and saw a spray--I thought it was a leak!

Comment: To jay613. The plumber worked for the builder. The builder instructed us to open the supply valve to use the garden hose. No mention was made of a bleeder port. We were watering our new lawn, I opened the supply valve and took off to water the lawn. 22 hours later I heard a dripping sound and the bottom floor was flooded I ran to the vanity and saw a spray--I thought it was a leak!  To ziptron: The bleeder valve was left open by the plumber when he installed it. The bleeder was left open to stop an air vacuum from forming, I guess. But he had installed a frost-free valve?

Comment: You should have started by saying this is a new home right away. If you didn't contract the plumber yourself then they only have to report to your builder and the home inspector. Your builder should have notified you of any quirks such as this. I am still having a hard time imagining what your system actually looks like so if you could share some relevant pictures then that would be most beneficial for everyone. Your heating sounds like a separate issue and should be asked as a new question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. They're expected to design and install to code and contract. Anything beyond that is a matter of professional courtesy to the customer or homeowner. I can't imagine one being unwilling to give you a few minutes to do so, and you'll be sure to take notes.

Comment: Indeed, and you can always ask to have additional details specified in the quote (run the pipe this way not that way, installs this and that, provide a drawing etc...), by which the plumber then has to abide as well to get paid. But this is not automatically required.

Comment: Sure. Please take the [tour] to learn how to follow up on your questions.