# If plumbers don't have to provide a plan to the homeowner, how does he know if what he paid for is being done?

Tags: plumbing

A plumber cut corners and this led to some flooding in our home. We wanted to obtain the plans from the builder so we could see if the plumber didn't stick to the original plans and that we paid for a better job.

Comment: Usually you pay the builder, they pay the plumber and the builder pays to fix any damage/problems.  Are you paying a builder to build your house, or buying a house from a builder?

Comment: Plumbing is usually a "get from point A to point B" endeavor. So if you received plumbing from point A to B and it all passed inspection then you'd have to go after the inspector. I don't know what caused your flood but if a nail in the wall created a leak and the bored hole wasn't guarded by a strike plate then that could be the plumber's or carpenter's fault. I don't think there is a single plumber in existence that will lay out everything they did from point A to point B. There's simply no benefit in doing so; time is money and I doubt you are willing to pay for plumbing blueprints.

Comment: If you want to have a serious fighting chance then read the code book and familiarize yourself with local ordinances so that you can decisively say "Look at this, this is thoroughly wrong."

Comment: I gave you an answer to your question but it is kind of suspect writing a question saying someone cut corners and expect help when you give no details on what corners they cut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are plumbers required to provide specs for the job they have done if asked by the homeowner?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221796/are-plumbers-required-to-provide-specs-for-the-job-they-have-done-if-asked-by-th) or Or this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/221838/18078 or in fact, every question you have asked so far, which are all the same question, really?

Comment: It could ba argued that operating valves and (de)winterization falls outside a layperson's use of faucets, flushing the toilet etc.. and is reasonably a task that requires knowledge of plumbing, but does not require a plumber to complete. So, did you have such knowledge at the time?

Comment: The short answer is that a plumbing contract is for functional fixtures of a specified nature installed to meet code, not some particular pipe route, size, or installation technique (for example).

Answer (score 2):

Cutting corners does not necessarily create liability.

Trade specialists like licensed plumbers, electricians and ticketed framers/carpenters are required by their licensing organization to adhere to certain standards, also known as "code".

The code sets technical standards for materials, layouts and workmanship that must be met. The code cannot be cut short. Installer can manage the cost by using alternative materials and supplies, but it is never an excuse for a leak due to faulty installation.

So, if they do the work you can expect that it meets these standards, and if it does not, they are liable. This part you (usually) won't find written in the contract.

For homes no drawings are required to demonstrate whether the work meets these standards.

You can simply have the work independently inspected against the standards. This can be initiated by you, by hiring an independent plumber after the work has been completed, or after a problem (a leak, noise, low pressure etc..) has been found

If you have asked for extras, such as more fixtures (double sink, bidet, separate shower and bath), larger pipes, pipe insulation, pressure regulated home runs etc... then that must be in the contract between you and the builder or plumber. If it's not there, only the code requirements are applied.

Where it gets sticky is determining what the cause of the leak is and who is liable: the plumber, the inspector, the supply manufacturer, a trades person doing work after the plumber...?

Comment: The previous 4 questions indicate that the leak was caused by the homeowner opening a valve without closing a bleed valve they were not aware of, which they want to blame the plumber for.

Comment: @Ecnerwal oh that story... yes I recall now, thanks for pointing it out. Well, I suppose this answer is useful to other readers. I think the OP is in for a point-of-view argument...

Answer (score 2):

The builder is liable for the plumber.   The plumber (in the US and many countries) would have had full inspections.   The city may be liable too - although taking the city to court has been tried and hardly ever successful.

The plans have no bearing on your issue.   You should take pictures of the current state and what caused the flooding.   If it was a code violation or wrong materials you could go to builder and recover.   Most states/countries have new home provisions that require builders to honor issues during a grace period that I have seen up to 10 years.

But to really really answer your question.

**Plumbing diagrams and plans, why we don't see them normally?**

Answer:  Are you going to pay for it?   What quality would you need it?   If the plumber found an issue while trying to produce the exact plans (framing in the way, whatever) and diverged from the plans would he need revisions in the contract with new plans?

For some plumbers they would write it in pencil and charge you extra - or maybe for free if it were a big job.   It certainly wouldn't be scaled or exact.   I have seen companies offer to do full diagrams and they come out to take pictures for their 3d software... This costs an insane amount of money compared to just getting the work done.   The companies that offer these services are smart because it is often to condo associations or businesses where they think having it in on paper equals better quality... its not.

Answer (score 0):

In my location (TX ) there are no plans for how the plumbing is done . My architect just drew in sinks , tubs. laundry, water heaters and toilets and it was up to the plumbing contractor to run the necessary pipes and drains. That was normal procedure  for the general contractor. The city inspected it at some point during construction.